# Join dataframe (tibble) with different column names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr, tibble

I'm looking for a dplyr solution to merge two df (or tibble) in dplyr, when they have the same langth, but different column names.

The solutions I found so far [relate to a common column](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) name, joined through the `by = ""` field.

The structure:

**df1**

```
A B
1 4
2 2
```

**df2**

```
C D
4 1
3 4
```

Desired output:

**df**

```
A B C D
1 4 4 1
2 2 3 4
```

Comment: `cbind(df1, df2)` ?

Comment: I think cbind does the job, the "merge" in the question was simply wrong (corrected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1,keep.rownames=T); setDT(df2,keep.rownames=T)
df3 <- df1[df2,on="rn"]
df3 <- subset(df3, select = -c(rn))
```

Approach taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062040/r-union-two-dataframe-with-different-column-names-and-no-match).

**EDIT**

You could reach a similar thing with `dplyr`

```
df1$rn <- seq.int(nrow(df1))
df2$rn <- seq.int(nrow(df2))
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = rn)
```

Comment: I appreciate the solution, though I prefer not to load another library :).

Comment: @Christopher I edited my answer so that it uses just `dplyr`